# Custom Transistion animation shows viewController with a blink

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am working with a custom transition, animation like that of a push.
But when i use this code after my viewcontroller loaded after after animation it just blinks.

Here is the method i used to present my view controller

```
+(void)leftpresentFrom:(UIViewController *)fromviewcontroller
                To:(UIViewController *)toviewcontroller
{

CGPoint newcenter       = CGPointMake(480, toviewcontroller.view.center.y);


toviewcontroller.view.center           =newcenter;


toviewcontroller.view.clipsToBounds=YES;


[fromviewcontroller.view addSubview:toviewcontroller.view];


[UIView animateWithDuration:.5
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{
                     toviewcontroller.view.center = CGPointMake(160 ,toviewcontroller.view.center.y);
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     [toviewcontroller.view removeFromSuperview];
                     [fromviewcontroller presentViewController:toviewcontroller animated:NO completion:^{

                     }];

                 }];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try removing the view after the new controller has been presented?

eg.

```
[fromviewcontroller presentViewController:toviewcontroller animated:NO completion:^{
    [toviewcontroller.view removeFromSuperview];
}];
```